# Crop and rotate photo selected by UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, photo

I want enable user to select a photo from a photo library on his iOS device (I assume using UIImagePickerController is a way to go for iPhone/iPod Touch?) and then crop the selected photo using a nice overlay. Rotate functionality would be nice to have as well.

1. Is UIImagePickerController a correct way to go as a photo selecting UI
2. Is there a simple way (ie. provided by framework or 3rd party, free libraries) to implement touch-enabled photo-cropping ui or do I have to do it "by hand"?
3. How about rotation?

Comment: You can definitely use UIImagePickerController to obtain the image from the user's photo library. Once the user selects the image there is a delegate method that passes you the UIImage they selected. Your delegate should then take that image and pass it to a custom view that has the editing capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As long as you don't need to be able to select multiple photos at once, UIImagePicker is a good choice.
2. I'd use CoreGraphics for this. Here's some info:
   http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/
3. CoreGraphics should also let you do rotation. Throw this in your CoreGraphics code:

   `CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));`

Comment: Unfortunately, link is dead now :(